# old data is shown when navigating back after an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have the following scenario while programming a shop using asp.net core 1.0 (mvc):

1. I add 3 products to my shop basket.
2. on the shop basket I delete one of the 3 products using an AJAX request. after the product has been deleted, I move on to the next step and become redirected to the page with the delivery & payment settings
3. on the page with the delivery & payment settings I choose to navigate back to the shop basket. I expect to see 2 products, but I see 3 since the page hasn’t been reloaded from the server.

when I inspect fiddler, I notice that no requests to the various resources of the shop basket are performed.

in my BaseController class I’ve already set the following code which should disable the cache:

```
[NonAction]
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{  
    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store, must-revalidate");
    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");
    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");

    await next();
}
```

does anybody have an idea about how we could navigate back and see the up-to-date shopping basket containing only 2 products?

Comment: I would suggest a return List of Products when you delete, and have that repopulate the view. The back button reloads what was on the page from last time.

Comment: Alternatively, if you aren't worried about austerity, just remove the deleted item manually as long as the ajax request was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this simply piece of code:

```
<head data-page-key="@string.Concat(this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], @"_", this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"])"
      data-page-token="@DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageKey = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getAttribute("data-page-key");
        var pageToken = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getAttribute("data-page-token");
        var pageTokenCached = sessionStorage[pageKey];
        if (!pageTokenCached || pageTokenCached !== pageToken) sessionStorage.setItem(pageKey, pageToken);
        else location.reload();
    </script>
```

The browser's **sessionStorage** stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

Here every time the page comes from server, a new data-page-token value is generated, stored in the  tag and saved in browser's sessionStorage.

When the user click on browser BACK botton, the html page is retrieved from the browser cache, and executed. So, the cached token is retrieved from sessionStorage, compared with what we have in the page, that is **data-page-token**.

If the values are equal it means that the page comes from browser cache otherwise it is a page coming from server.

When **data-page-token** is equals to **sessionStorage's token**, it means that we have a stale page and so it is reload, otherwise is processed.

session Storage is compatible with all browser and also supported by IE 8.0

Comment: This is incredibly clever!